# The titles of pages with suggested edits change on the screen but not in the title bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

After users submit suggested edits, they get taken back to the edited posts. For them, the posts look like they already have edits applied, and come with the following disclaimer:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

However, the changes don't show up in the browser title bar. Example:

[image: new title shows up on page but old title remains in title bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, we have to draw the line somewhere on how intrusive the code is on the check/pseudo-application over top of the normal page load.  That line is just short of the browser title - this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).